# ggplot2: Column labels disappear when renamed

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have written code that works great at making a ggplot, however, once I try to rename my labels something goes awry and all of the x axis labels are removed. This does not happen for a very similar plot that I make.

Here's the head of my data:

```
Variety Rate Hollow Double Knob       AllCWT.AC ValueCWT.AC TuberSize
1 Burbank    1     67     42  351 AVGCWT.AC.10.13   11.930449  10-13 oz
2 Burbank    2     65     43  391 AVGCWT.AC.10.13   13.123357  10-13 oz
3 Burbank    3     64     42  362 AVGCWT.AC.10.13   11.755755  10-13 oz
4 Burbank    4     63     43  348 AVGCWT.AC.10.13    6.982759  10-13 oz
5 Burbank    5     67     48  357 AVGCWT.AC.10.13    8.029106  10-13 oz
6   Hodag    1     81     50  470 AVGCWT.AC.10.13   46.216253  10-13 oz
```

And here is my ggplot2 code:

```
WSYPnoCull <- ggplot(data=LongMrkSizeProfile,aes(x=Rate,y=ValueCWT.AC,group=interaction(TuberSize,Variety),fill=(TuberSize))) +
  geom_col(position = "stack",inherit.aes = TRUE) +
  facet_wrap(~Variety,nrow=2) +
  ggtitle("Water Study Size Profile, No culls (CWT/ac)") +
  ylab("Yield Averages (CWT/ac)") +
  xlab("Rate (Percentage of ET)")  +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = c('125%','100%','75%', '50%', '75%50%')) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1)) 

print(WSYPnoCull)
```

The line that causes the original labels to be removed but not replaced is this one:

```
scale_x_discrete(labels = c('125%','100%','75%', '50%', '75%50%'))
```

Any idea what could be going wrong here? Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: could you please provide your data with `dput(your_data)` or `dput(head(your_data))`

Comment: just drop the `xlab` line and insert the label string as first argument of `scale_x_discrete`

Comment: it might be because your `rate` variable for the x axis is numeric and not a factor, and you're using `scale_x_discrete` - if you include `factor(Rate)` in your `aes` does it show up?